# PHP include file again to refresh content

Tags: php, include, refresh

- I've PHP page let's say test1.php
- At the beginning of this page I've one include statement, let's say (head.php)
- Content in this include goes on the top of the output.
- After this include, I perform some calculations, result of which need to displayed in the head.php
- To update header, if i re-include head.php ; it's showing previous as well as new content (something like overlapping content)

Is there any way to refresh content of previously included head.php [without overwriting it)

Comment: have you tried looking into something called AJAX?

Comment: so you want to update the html that is outputted in head.php?

Comment: @Satya; Yes, but that was complicating logic in my code. Is there any way to refresh head.php before output is displayed on the browser. As control is still with server when value is changed, i was looking for option using php. Kindly correct me , if I'm going in wrong direction.

Comment: @gwillie ; yes your are correct.

Comment: If you have html in a variable ie it hasn't left the buffer yet, then 2 options exist; [DomDocument](http://php.net/domdocument‎) and god forbid regex. With `DomDocument` you can manipulate html markup like it was clay